# Logging in to ssh doesn't ask for password, but scp does

Tags: ssh, putty, scp

I am logging in to my (Rackspace) server using `ssh` via `putty` where it doesn't prompt for a password.

But using the same IP if I transfer files via `scp`, I am prompted for a password.

How could I overcome this?

Comment: What exactly do you want to overcome? The fact that it asks for a password? Or the fact that it doesnt? And how are you authenticating in PuTTY?

Comment: Actually the admin said it will not ask for password during login and yea it worked as he said...but while transferring files via scp it is asking for pasword how come it happens????

Comment: You have probably set up PuTTY to use an SSH key or single-sign-on

Comment: How an i do that could you please explain me?

Comment: been a while re putty, but what he's saying is that the program you're using SCP for is not Putty(maybe putty can't). Putty is configured to use a key (or SSO), (probably key!).. But your SCP program might not be. I'd suggest you could try PSCP it may be similar to putty in terms of configuring a key, and you've already got it done for Putty. Whoever configured putty for you might know how to configure PSCP for you and then you can answer your own question, with some credit to qasdfdsaq